# life cycle of the Secure element

Tags: nfc, secure-element

I was looking into different resources to find clear explanation about "life cycle of the Secure element" . the buzz phrase is every where on NFC materials but no clear diagram or defined state of "life cycle "

Could anyone shed a light on this please ? any direction for resource to would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [GlobalPlatform](http://globalplatform.org/) card specification, it is covered in depth.